# Google API in Java vs. Struts

Tags: java

If I use the below method to get the token of Google account using a normal Java project, it works absolutely fine, but if I use that same code in my Struts project, it gives me a `ClassNotFoundException`. Could someone please tell me why it is throwing the exception? I am lost.

```
public String Login(String username,String password){
    String token = null;
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     String postURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
     List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accountType", "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE"));
     nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", username));
     nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwd", password));
     nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", "cp"));// Name of Google service 
     nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", "feras-MeAndTheGreenRobot-1.0"));
     UrlEncodedFormEntity ent;
     try {
             ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
             post.setEntity(ent);
             HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
             HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
             if (resEntity != null) {
                      String authToken=  EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                     System.out.println("RESPONSE is "+ authToken );
 token = authToken.substring(authToken.indexOf("Auth=") + 5, authToken.length()).trim();
                     System.out.println("Auth is "+  authToken.substring(authToken.indexOf("Auth=") + 5, authToken.length()).trim());
             }
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return token;
}
```

Exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
at com.struts.action.LoginAction.submit(LoginAction.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:404)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:184)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you put under the `"WEB-INF/lib"` folder of your web project the jar library files used by `HttpClient`?

Comment: I tried in Eclipse as well as Netbeans but its not working in both

Comment: Can you send the complete list of jars that you put in "WEB-INF/lib" folder of your eclipse web project?

Comment: gwt-dev-2.4.0-rc1.jar , commons-logging-1.1.1.jar , struts2-core-2.0.14.jar + all other struts 2 lib

Comment: And where are the jars about the `HttpClient`?

Comment: gwt-dev-2.4.0-rc1.jar  is for HttpClient

Comment: I cannot find any HttpClient class in the GWT package. Look at the [doc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html). Event for the version 2.4.0-rc1.

Comment: Check This http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.4.0-rc1/org/apache/http/client/version.properties?av=f                                          and inside the package org you will find the HttpCLient class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Comment: There are no class in that package (only a `version.properties` file), maybe it is used by maven to download the dependencies. But in this moment your web application is running without the necessary jar. Try to get the http client 4.0.1 and put it in your WEB-INF/lib.